# ungrib.exe is not created for compiling WPS

Tags: wps

I compiled WRF without any problem, but in compiling WPS, it makes metgrib and geogrid.exe but unfotunatly it doesn't make ungrib.exe.
do you know what shall I do with it? how can I solve the question
Thank you very much in advance .
can you help me plese.?